# How can I draw Hangman in Bash without embedding echo statements for each case?

Tags: bash, ascii-art

I'm making a Hangman in Bash for a assignment. It completly works but one part of it is so badly coded that it causes a kind of itch. I'm talking about printing the progress of "hanging the man"

```
print_hangman(){

if [[ $attempts = 0 ]]
then
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ""

elif [[ $attempts = 1 ]]
then
    echo "      "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "_______________"

elif [[ $attempts = 2 ]]
then
    echo "      "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               "
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "_______________|"

elif [[ $attempts = 3 ]]
then
    echo "         "
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "_______________|"

elif [[ $attempts = 4 ]]
then
    echo "      __________"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "_______________|"

elif [[ $attempts = 5 ]]
then
    echo "      __________"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "   _/_\_       |"
    echo "    |_|        |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "_______________|"

elif [[ $attempts = 6 ]]
then
    echo "      __________"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "   _/_\_       |"
    echo "    |_|        |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "_______________|"

elif [[ $attempts = 7 ]]
then
    echo "      __________"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "   _/_\_       |"
    echo "    |_|        |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "    /          |"
    echo "   /           |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "_______________|"

elif [[ $attempts = 8 ]]
then
    echo "      __________"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "   _/_\_       |"
    echo "    |_|        |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "    / \        |"
    echo "   /   \       |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "_______________|"

elif [[ $attempts = 9 ]]
then
    echo "      __________"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "   _/_\_       |"
    echo "    |_|        |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo " ----|         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "    / \        |"
    echo "   /   \       |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "_______________|"

elif [[ $attempts = 10 ]]
then
    echo "      __________"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "   _/_\_       |"
    echo "    |_|        |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo " ----|----     |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "     |         |"
    echo "    / \        |"
    echo "   /   \       |"
    echo "               |"
    echo "_______________|"
fi

}
```

Is there a way in Bash to make this code take less lines? I was thinking maybe if you could take the standard and then only write lines for the lines that are changing. For example on attempt = 1 you'd only have to change one out of 13 lines.

Comment: lol.. +1 for fun...

Comment: Eh? This is StackOverflow, [where we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: ...and if this is a "find the shortest way to do X" challenge, then it's code golf, and belongs over [Code Golf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ...whereas if it's a request for suggestions on how to improve working code, with quality as opposed to terseness as foremost goal, then there's an argument to be made for [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy please forgive me :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe?

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -d '' hex <<'EOF'
1f8b080025bbce580003535040055c0ac3488067b038841a02f16860b0f8
ae862a02689eab21ec3bead84b1f015cbe438acdc1e254320488f55d0dba
216802f1faf131f1282a6ae26bd0b4d0dc331802f4f41d2133881118d6be
d347f30c127f58f82e06c37731a85a0685ef74816098fb0e44d0d777004c
bdfc0d8a090000
EOF
mapfile -d$'\014' frames < <(printf "%b" $(sed 's/../\\x& /g' <<<"$hex") |gzip -d)
#here you have the array "frames[@]" - with the pictures

for frame in "${frames[@]}"
do
    clear
    printf "%s\n" "$frame"
    sleep 0.3
done
```

it your `bash` doesn't supports `mapfile -d`, instead of the line `mapfile -d ....` you can use:

```
n=0
while IFS=$'\014' read -r -d $'\014' f
do
        frames[$n]="$f"
        let n++
done < <(printf "%b" $(sed 's/../\\x& /g' <<<"$hex") |gzip -d)
```

How it works:

- The pictures are stored as gziped hex-encoded string.
- the `sed 's/../\\x& /g'` convert the string to list of `\x1f \x8b`
- the `printf "%b"` prints the characters
- and finally the `gzip -d` decodes the whole stream
- the "stream" is a series of frames each divided by the `^L` (CTRL-L) character
- the `mapfile` reads the stream into the array `frame` using the delimiter `^L`
- done :)

output - every frame like bellow

```
________________







               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
_______________|

               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
_______________|
      __________
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
_______________|
      __________
     |         |
     |         |
   _/_\_       |
    |_|        |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
               |
_______________|
      __________
     |         |
     |         |
   _/_\_       |
    |_|        |
     |         |
     |         |
     |         |
     |         |
               |
               |
               |
_______________|
      __________
     |         |
     |         |
   _/_\_       |
    |_|        |
     |         |
     |         |
     |         |
     |         |
    /          |
   /           |
               |
_______________|
      __________
     |         |
     |         |
   _/_\_       |
    |_|        |
     |         |
     |         |
     |         |
     |         |
    / \        |
   /   \       |
               |
_______________|
      __________
     |         |
     |         |
   _/_\_       |
    |_|        |
     |         |
 ----|         |
     |         |
     |         |
    / \        |
   /   \       |
               |
_______________|
      __________
     |         |
     |         |
   _/_\_       |
    |_|        |
     |         |
 ----|----     |
     |         |
     |         |
    / \        |
   /   \       |
               |
_______________|
```

How to create the hex-string

- create one file per frame, like `xx00`, `xx01`, ...
- use the following `make_hex.sh` as `bash make_hex.sh xx*`

```
mk_stream() {
    for file in "$@"
    do
        cat "$file"
        printf "%c" $'\014'
    done
}
mk_stream "$@" | gzip | xxd -ps
```

Comment: Heh. I may not be a fan of the question, but this is a darned impressive answer. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hear such words from you - best moment of my day! :)

Comment: From 324 lines to 147 lines, sorry for not realizing it should've been on Code Golf, I really appreciate your help tho and it looks incredibly fancy now. Genius to Encode/Decode it

Comment: @StrahBehry you welcome & enjoy! :) _also, me only reduced your 180 lines to 25_. I know nothing about the remainig lines up to 324. :)

Comment: @jm666 co-student gets 'mapfile: -d: invalid option' updated Bash to latest version, do you happen to know what is up? Google actually doesn't have a answer.

Comment: @StrahBehry If they updated to latest version it must work. The `mapfile with `-d` is introduced in `bash v4.4`. Maybe they need just reload the shell (relog?). Also, the `readarray` builtin does the same as `mapfile`. My `bash --version` shows `4.4.12(1)-release`.

Comment: @StrahBehry also added a modification - _could_ work with older `bash`es.

Comment: @jm666 manually installed Bash 4.4, works fine now, didn't update with apt-get upgrade for some reason. Once again thanks so much absolutely amazing

Comment: @StrahBehry - enjoy! Unlike others's common view - I like the fun. :)

Comment: @StrahBehry Congrats. :) nice game!!! Still needs a bit cleaning, but it is definitely a nice one. :D

Comment: @jm666 if you have any suggestions please tell, we're currently not aware of some maybe obvious things.